# How can I process a list of files that includes spaces in its names in Unix?

Tags: macos, unix, list, shell, file

I'm trying to list the files in a directory and do something to them in the Mac OS X prompt.

It should go like this: for f in $(ls -1); do echo $f; done

If I have files without spaces in their names (fileA.txt, fileB.txt), the echo works fine.
If the files include spaces in their names ("file A.txt", "file B.txt"), I get 4 strings (file, A.txt, file, B.txt).

I've tried quoting the listing command, but it only changed the problem.

If I do this: for f in $(ls -1); do echo $f; done
I get: file A.txt\nfile B.txt

(It displays correctly, but it is a single string and I need the 2 lines separated.

Answer (score 12):

Step away from ls if at all possible. Use find from the findutils package.

`find /target/path -type f -print0 | xargs -0 your_command_here`

`-print0` will cause find to output the names separated by NUL characters (ASCII zero). The `-0` argument to xargs tells it to expect the arguments separated by NUL characters too, so everything will work just fine.

Replace `/target/path` with the path under which your files are located.

`-type f` will only locate files. Use `-type d` for directories, or omit altogether to get both.

Replace `your_command_here` with the command you'll use to process the file names. (Note: If you run this from a shell using echo for your_command_here you'll get everything on one line - don't get confused by that shell artifact, xargs will do the expected right thing anyway.)

Edit: Alternatively (or if you don't have xargs), you can use the much less efficient

`find /target/path -type f -exec your_command_here \{\} \;`

`\{\} \;` is the escape for `{} ;` which is the placeholder for the currently processed file. find will then invoke `your_command_here` with `{} ;` replaced by the file name, and since `your_command_here` will be launched by find and not by the shell the spaces won't matter.

The second version will be less efficient since find will launch a new process for each and every file found. xargs is smart enough to pipe the commands to a newly launched process if it can figure it's safe to do so. Prefer the xargs version if you have the choice.

Comment: xargs doesn't work so well if you need to run more than one command on a file. Of course, you can use a shell script as the single command.

Comment: True. There's always the -exec argument to find then (although, as you pointed out, most problems can be rephrased using xargs via a separate shell script.)

Answer (score 10):

```
for f in *; do echo "$f"; done
```

should do what you want. Why are you using `ls` instead of `*` ?

In general, dealing with spaces in shell is a PITA. Take a look at the `$IFS` variable, or better yet at Perl, Ruby, Python, etc.

Comment: If a simple ls -1 is all that's required, then yes: replace it with *. OP might have other requirements though - I always hit this issue when doing things to files in time modified order, for example.

Comment: Well, whenever you use ls, you're going to have this issue more or less, because file names can have newlines. You'll need to switch to some other approach (e.g., find/xargs, perl/ruby/python, bash arrays + a lot of work)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an answer using $IFS as discussed by **derobert**
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/handling-filenames-with-spaces-in-bash.html

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the arguments into `read`. For example, to `cat` all files in the directory:

```
ls -1 | while read FILENAME; do cat "$FILENAME"; done
```

This means you can still use `ls`, as you have in your question, or any other command that produces `$IFS` delimited output.

The `while` loop makes it much easier to do several things to the argument, and makes complex processing more readable in my opinion. A contrived example:

```
ls -1 | while read FILE
do
    echo 1: "$FILE"
    echo 2: "$FILE"
done
```

Comment: That helps if there are just spaces (and tabs); it doesn't help if there are newlines in the names.  find -print0 and xargs -0 does help in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

look --quoting-style option.
for instance, --quoting-style=c would produce :

> $ ls --quoting-style=c
>
> "file1"   "file2" "dir one"

Answer (score -1):

Check out the manpage for xargs:

it works like this:

ls -1 /tmp/*.jpeg | xargs rm

Comment: That is at most a small part of the answer - and without a more complete explanation, your answer is of no help.